# Regex for validating ratios such as Y39.29/28h

Tags: javascript, php, regex

I am trying to write a regular expression which has to adhere the following rules:

```
Y120.001/100.232k
↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑
| | | | | | | | This k may be any letter, is not required
| | | | | | | Another number if there was a dot
| | | | | | A dot, not required
| | | | | A number with at least one digit, not required if a letter follows
| | | | Always a slash
| | | If there's a dot, digits can follow
| | A dot, not required
| A number, at least one digit
Always Y
```

These strings should work:

- Y120.001/1k
- Y1/h
- Y2039/100
- Y29/47.0

These should not work:

- x203/493s (Not a Y at the start)
- Y/39x (No number after the Y)
- Y83839 (Second half missing)
- <strike>Y78/29 (Last letter missing)</strike>

This is my early attempt, but it does not work in PHP:

```
/^\$*(\d)*(.*(\d))\/*(.*(\d))*.$
```

Comment: You write that the last letter is not required and the second number is also not required, does that mean that Y123/ is a valid string?

Comment: @klarki about the number it says "not required if a letter follows". I understand it like this: you can have it without the letter or without the number but not without both, that is `Y123/1` -> valid, `Y123/x` -> valid, `Y123/` -> not valid.

Comment: is there any solution for this ..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34327142/ng-pattern-for-validating-ratio#34327142

Answer (score 2):

This pattern should work:

```
^Y\d+(\.\d*)?/(\d+(\.\d*)?[a-z]?|[a-z])$
```

[**Demonstration**](http://regexpal.com/?flags=gm&regex=%5EY%5Cd%2B%28%5C.%5Cd%2a%29%3F%2F%28%5Cd%2B%28%5C.%5Cd%2a%29%3F%5Ba-z%5D%3F%7C%5Ba-z%5D%29%24&input=Y120.001%2F1k%0AY1%2Fh%0AY2039%2F100%0AY29%2F47.0%0A%0A%0Ax203%2F493s%0AY%2F39x%0AY83839)

Answer (score 1):

In javascript

```
re=/^Y\d+(\.\d+)?\/([a-z]$|\d+(\.\d+)?[a-z]?$)/

"Y120.001/1k Y1/h Y2039/100 Y29/47.0".split(" ").map(function(s) { return re.test(s) })
> [true, true, true, true]

"x203/493s Y/39x Y83839 Y78/29".split(" ").map(function(s) { return re.test(s) })
> [false, false, false, true]
```

This does accept `Y78/29` as the trailing letter is optional.

Answer (score 1):

After several iterations to correct for commented shortcomings:

```
/^Y\d+(?:\.\d+)?\/(?:(?:\d+(?:\.\d+)?)[A-Za-z]?|[A-Za-z])$/
```

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/nSU65/4/)

Old Answer:

Here is a fully specific version that works well.

```
/^Y\d+(?:\.\d+)?\/(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)?[A-Za-z]?$/
```

Edited for a follow-up test in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nSU65/1/)

Comment: I updated for a small syntax change to allow the 'Y1/h' match.

Comment: Nice :)  New version also matches `Y1/`, which seems to violate the rules.

Comment: Added more tests to the demo for a couple of edge cases.

Do the rules make Y1./12.1k valid?

Answer (score 0):

```
^Y\d+\.?\d*/((\d+\.?\d*)[a-zA-Z]?|(\d+\.?\d*)?[a-zA-Z])$
```

You can check the explanation of the regex from [here](http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl).

Comment: This also matches `Y1/`, which isn't given as a sample input, but it seems to violate the rules.

Comment: Matches `Y120./1k also` (a dot without digits after it) !

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the nuances of your specification

```
\bY\d+(?:\.\d*)?/(?:[A-Za-z]|(?:\d+(?:\.\d+)?[A-Za-z]?))\b
```

I understand your specification to include that if the first dot is present, the following number(s) is/are optional; but if the 2nd dot is present, there must be at least one following number.  Others seem to have interpreted that part of your requirements differently.

Answer (score 0):

this pattern should work `Y[\d.]+\/[\d.]*[a-z]?` [Demo](http://regex101.com/r/aE4pI8)

Answer (score 0):

What about the following one?

```
var r = /^Y\d+(\.\d+)?\/(\d+(\.\d+)?|(\d+(\.\d+)?)?[A-Za-z])$/;
console.log(true  === r.test('Y120.001/1k')); // true
console.log(true  === r.test('Y1/h'));        // true
console.log(true  === r.test('Y2039/100'));   // true
console.log(true  === r.test('Y29/47.0'));    // true
console.log(false === r.test('x203/493s'));   // true
console.log(false === r.test('Y/39x'));       // true
console.log(false === r.test('Y83839'));      // true
```

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
/Y\d+\.?\d*\/\d+\.?\d*\w?/
```

Comment: This fails with "Y1/h" (mentioned in the question) and "Y123/k" (valid by the rules described).