# ng-pattern for validating ratio

Tags: angularjs, regex

I have given a pattern validation for input text box as

```
 ng-pattern="^(2[0-3]|[01]?[0-9]):([0-5]?[0-9])$"
```

Its not throwing any validation for the buttons.
Full implementation is here:

```
<form name="configurationForm">                              
<div class="form-group">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Ratio (Eg:3:1)" ng-pattern="^([0-9]):([0-9])$" ng-model="configuration.stripRatio" name="stripRatio" required />
  <span class="error pop_up" ng-show="configurationForm.stripRatio.$error.pattern">Please enter only ratio..Eg:3:1</span>
</div>
</form>
<button ng-disabled="configurationForm.$invalid">Save</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it

```
ng-pattern="/^([0-9]+):([0-9]+)$/"
```

OR

```
ng-pattern="/^(\d+):(\d+)$/"
```

Your are forget to put `"/"`, and also use [`"+"`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp) quantifier

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried it but it seems your **`ng-pattern`** is incorrect it should be like this **`"/^([1-9]+[0-9]*):([1-9]+[0-9]*)$/"`**